# when I am adding Long Press Gesture on uiimageview in Table View Cell .Uiimageview Is not showing With correct Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am Using the Long Press Gesture code on uiimageview the Problem is Profile Picture is not showing Correct.I have 50 values in Table View and after 5 to 6 images Further Cell image is going to be Nil.and Profile Picture is coming from Web Service.and if i will not add long press all 50 rows will display with their correct Image.
this is my code::

```
#pragma mark - UITableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrResultData.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FishCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // getting the imag which is in prototype cell in storyboard
    UIImageView *cellimg=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    cellimg.tag=indexPath.row;
    cellimg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer =   [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    gestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    [cellimg addGestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer];
    [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(imgLongPressed:)];

    - (void)imgLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender
    {
        //  UIImageView *view_ =(UIImageView*) sender.view;
        NSLog(@"view tag %ld",sender.view.tag);
        //    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view_.superview];
        //
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            Profile_PopUP_Vc *Profile_PopUPVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile_PopUP_Vc"];
            Profile_PopUPVc.ImageUrl=[[arrResultData valueForKey:@"picture"]objectAtIndex:sender.view.tag];
            Profile_PopUPVc.strUsername=[[arrResultData valueForKey:@"username"]objectAtIndex:sender.view.tag];
            Profile_PopUPVc.delegate = self;
            [self presentPopupViewController:Profile_PopUPVc animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
        }
        else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
            [self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're adding a new gesture recognizer every time cell is reused, don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get indexpath using view's hierarchy and use this indexpath instead of its tag value .

```
UIImageView *view_ =(UIImageView*) sender.view
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view_.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [recipeCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
Profile_PopUPVc.ImageUrl=[[arrResultData valueForKey:@"picture"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thankuu so much... KKRocks :) (Y)

Comment: I am Using Long Press my whole Application. i have side Menu where m using table view with header and table view header is contain Profile Image. here the Problem is Long Press is not working on uiiageview in header.
Can u Please Suggest me What s the Problem is being here.

Comment: you need to set IBoutlet of imageview and add gesture to this imageview.

Comment: Here we are creating the Header of table view programmatically, as we know all subviews in header will also create with code.

Comment: ok then you can also set gesture in  imageview without IBoutlet . and also mention code of header view.

Comment: This Is My Code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125920/discussion-between-kkrocks-and-user6898211).

Answer (score 1):

The error is in those lines:

```
UIImageView *cellimg=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
cellimg.tag=indexPath.row;
```

You are changing the image view tag, and then, when cell is being reused, it doesn't have a view with tag 101, so your `cellimg` is `nil`.

Comment: I am setting the Particular index path for getting the Image Where User will Tap on Image. so how can i Remove My Problem.Thanks For Reply.

Comment: Create a custom subclass for your table view cell, connect it in storyboard and create an IBOutlet for your image view. than, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, use smth like MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FishCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; cell.myImageView.tag = indexPath.row; and so on

Answer (score 0):

Remove all gesture from imageView in cell for row at indexpath First

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in cellimg.gestureRecognizers) {
    [cellimg removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

and then add the gesture as you use in mentioned code.
Use like this because when cell For row called the cell is reused so wrong image get selected.